# Is there any locking mechanisms for table object in SQL developer?

Tags: sql

In my multiuser database, the statements within multiple simultaneous transactions can update the same data in a table. I have to restrict access of data until one transactions gets complete

I had heard about Data Concurrency & Consistency but could not understand

Comment: Way too broad subject. Read about transactions.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: The second transaction that tries to UPDATE a row that has been locked by a different transaction will automatically wait for the first transaction to commit or rollback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options.

**1) Lock the entire table with TABLOCKX:**

If you are in a transaction and you grab an exclusive lock on a table, EG:

```
SELECT 1 FROM TABLE WITH (TABLOCKX)
```

No other processes will be able to grab any locks on the table, meaning all queries attempting to talk to the table will be blocked until the transaction commits.

**2) Use manual application locks:**

[sp_getapplock (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs[^]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[sp_releaseapplock (Transact-SQL) | Microsoft Docs[^]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: "SQL Developer" in the questions title seems to indicate that Ellen is using Oracle rather than Microsoft SQL Server. The tag `sql` refers to the query language "SQL", not to the database product from Microsoft